# JSON replace all empty values with a default string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

JSON has many empty values, where I want to replace the empty value with a default string.

```
var json= [
{
    "machineNum": "1A",
    "serialNo": "123",
    "city": ""
},
{
    "machineNum": "2B",
    "serialNo": "",
    "city": ""
},
{
    "machineNum": "3A",
    "serialNo": "123",
    "city": "NewCity"
}
]

 var newJson=json.replace("","Not AVailable");
 console.log(newJson);
```

So wherever there is **"" - empty value** replace with default value "Not Available"

The above is not working.

[JSFIDDLE here](http://jsfiddle.net/EFTZR/509/)

Comment: It could work if you used it on the JSON string, and not the parsed JSON object.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to do a replace on the `json` string not a `javascript` object.  Also you aren't looking for `""` you are looking for `"\"\""`:

```
var json= [
{
    "machineNum": "1A",
    "serialNo": "123",
    "city": ""
},
{
    "machineNum": "2B",
    "serialNo": "",
    "city": ""
},
{
    "machineNum": "3A",
    "serialNo": "123",
    "city": "NewCity"
}
]
var temp = JSON.stringify(json);
temp = temp.replace(/\"\"/g, "\"Not Available\"");
json = JSON.parse(temp);
console.log(json);
```

Console Output:

[image]

Comment: it is replacing the first occurrence of "" (empty). other remains "" (empty) instead of Not Available.

Comment: You could use the global modifier for the regex. Replace this line:>>       temp = temp.replace(/""/g, "\"Not Available\"");

Comment: Nice answer, +1

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to stringify/reparse the json, you could loop over the array and each property of the objects in the array.

```
json.forEach(function (machine) {
    Object.keys(machine).forEach(function (key) {
        if (machine[key] === '' && machine.hasOwnProperty(key)) machine[key] = 'Not Available';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.map` along with `Object.keys` to make sure all key-value pairs which have empty value are all applied with default string. See a quick example below:

```
function replaceEmpty(json, defaultStr){
    return json.map(function (el){
        Object.keys(el).forEach(function(key){
            el[key] = el[key] || defaultStr;
        });
        return el;
    });
}

var result = replaceEmpty(json,"Not Available");
```

**Output**

> [{"machineNum":"1A","serialNo":"123","city":"Not Available"},{"machineNum":"2B","serialNo":"Not Available","city":"Not Available"},{"machineNum":"3A","serialNo":"123","city":"NewCity"}]